# How much battery would drain an Android service with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, battery

Lets put the following service in as an example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    final BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Do nothing
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
    }

}
```

Note that THIS BroadcastReceiver requires being registered at RUNTIME (lets say, Service or Activity). That is the reason I am using a Service

Supposing that this Service is going to be running the whole time the device is turned on, have a working BroadcastReceiver and is doing nothing, would it drain battery life? If it would, how much? Can make it running make the Android framework drain more battery due to have a Service or Broadcast Receiver running?

I know, I am a battery life maniac

Answer (score 2):

A `BroadcastReciever` itself does not consume much battery. The task that you do inside it decides how much battery is drained.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549635/do-android-broadcast-receivers-consume-battery-life) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239809/exactly-how-much-power-is-drained-by-registering-a-broadcast-receiver-for-action).